# How to use logger to print messages with assert

Tags: junit, log4j2, assertj

I am trying to implement a logger in my repo and I am having some issues with implementing logger with Junit.

Sample assertion:

```
logger.info("Asserting the response.");
assertThat(response.statusCode())
                    .withFailMessage("The test failed with status code:" + response.statusCode())
                    .isEqualTo(200);
```

I want to use logger.error() function in place of withFailMessage but I can't seem to find any method.

Comment: `withFailMessage` only manipulates the error message of the `AssertionError` raised when the assertion fails. I am not sure I understood your target. Would you like to avoid the `AssertionError` and have a logged event instead?

Comment: Yea. Just do the same action but using logger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard assertions (i.e., `assertThat()`) are meant to fail immediately with an `AssertionError`.

If you would like to have custom logic in case of failures, [Soft Assertions](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-soft-assertions) together with the [callback feature](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-soft-assertions-collect-listener) might be what you are looking for.

Your example would become something like:

```
SoftAssertions softly = new SoftAssertions();
softly.setAfterAssertionErrorCollected(error -> logger.error("Assertion failed: {}", error));

softly.assertThat(response.statusCode())
      .isEqualTo(200);
```